# how to fix below Error while parsing json swift ios?

Tags: json, swift

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead., NSCodingPath=(
>       "CodingKeys(stringValue: \"data\", intValue: nil)"
>   )}

```
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        do {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(DiscoverData.self, from: data!)
            print(responseModel)
        } catch let error as NSError{
            print("error description : \(error)")
        }
    }).resume()
    }

struct DiscoverData : Decodable{
    var status : String?
    var message : String?
    var playlists : [Playlist]?

}
extension DiscoverData{
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case message
        case playlists = "data"
    }
}

struct Playlist : Decodable{
    var name : String
    var videos : [Video]?
}
struct Video : Decodable{
    var id : String
    var name : String
    var description : String?
    var image_url : String?
}


extension Video {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case description
        case image_url = "thumbnail"

    }
}
```

[image: image shows api response format]

Comment: sorry, i have just updated decode command.

Comment: your code looks fine to me but still debugging except can you please try changing id as Int under Video?

Comment: change it to try jsonDecoder.decode([DiscoverData].self, from: data!)

Comment: tried both ways, still getting same error.

Comment: did yo try this jsonDecoder.decode([DiscoverData].self ?

Comment: yes, but getting same error still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201728/discussion-between-reed-and-matrix).

Comment: please reply to chat

Comment: Okay but now post the actual JSON. Don't show us a picture. Provide actual code and actual data.

Comment: Till that try this https://www.json4swift.com

Comment: hey , looks like i have found where the problem is. so sometime request was failing and i was getting empty data dictionary (not an array). and thats why it was throwing json parsing exception.

Comment: how can i handle both use case ? array of values and empty dictionary.

Comment: In your closure you also have an error parameter so first check it and only decode if it is nil otherwise handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
 let responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode([DiscoverData].self, from: data!)
```

Comment: still getting same error : error description : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead." UserInfo={NSCodingPath=(
), NSDebugDescription=Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.}

Comment: hey , looks like i have found where the problem is. so sometime request was failing and i was getting empty data dictionary (not an array). and thats why it was throwing json parsing exception. 
how can i handle both use case ? array of values and empty dictionary

Comment: That's cool man! and did you try [DiscoverData] or DiscoverData?

Comment: using optional "?"

Comment: we can do that by using DiscoverData?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for comments. I have found solution. As sometimes API used to return data object as an array of elements and sometime empty dictionary with other error messages.

i have handled both use cases.

do {

```
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
           let result = try jsonDecoder.decode(DiscoverData.self, from: data!)
           print(result)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
           let result = try jsonDecoder.decode(ErrorData.self, from: data!)
           print(result)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)

    }
```

Comment: That's very interesting but there was no way to know this from your question, so this is not a valid answer to the question as posed.